# How do drag&drop on pure phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, phantomjs

How do drag&drop on pure phantomjs without casperjs, selenium, etc?

I tried this code, but it does not work

```
var page = new WebPage();
page.open("http://html5demos.com/drag", function()
{
  var coordOne = page.evaluate(function() { return document.getElementById("one").getBoundingClientRect(); });    
  var coordBin = page.evaluate(function() { return document.getElementById("bin").getBoundingClientRect(); });

  console.log(coordOne.left + "x" + coordOne.top);  
  console.log(coordBin.left + "x" + coordBin.top);

  page.sendEvent("mousemove", coordOne.left, coordOne.top);
  page.render('screenshot1.png');

  page.sendEvent("mousedown", coordOne.left, coordOne.top);  
  page.sendEvent("mousemove", coordBin.left, coordBin.top); 
  page.sendEvent("mouseup", coordBin.left, coordBin.top);  
  page.render('screenshot2.png');

  phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read that it's not working in html5. In normal code it works:

```
var page = new WebPage();
page.open("http://www.snook.ca/technical/mootoolsdragdrop/", function()
{
  var coordOne = page.evaluate(function() { return document.getElementById("dragger").getBoundingClientRect(); });    
  var coordBin = page.evaluate(function() { return document.getElementsByClassName("item")[0].getBoundingClientRect(); });

  console.log(coordOne.left + "x" + coordOne.top);  
  console.log(coordBin.left + "x" + coordBin.top);

  page.sendEvent("mousedown", coordOne.left+1, coordOne.top+1);  
  page.sendEvent("mousemove", coordBin.left+1, coordBin.top+1);
  page.sendEvent("mouseup", coordBin.left+1, coordBin.top+1);  

  page.render('screenshot.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Strange, because the [documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html): *For `'mousemove'`, however, there is no button pressed (i.e. it is not dragging).*